# Struggling with recovering the associated graded vector space in A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, spectral-sequences

I've made it through a grand total of 1 page of John McCleary's A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences before getting stuck.

Let $H^*$ be a graded $k$-vector space, and that it is filtered

$$H^*= F^0H^*\supset \dots\supset F^nH^*\supset F^{n+1}H^* \supset \dots \supset \{0\}$$

then the associated graded vector space $E^p_0(H^*)$ is defined by $E^p_0(H^*) = F^pH^*/F^{p+1}H^*$. We can give this a bigrading by defining $F^pH^r = F^pH^*\cap H^r$ and then

$$E^{p,q}_0 = F^pH^{p+q}/F^{p+1}H^{p+q}$$

On page 4, the following is written about the definition of $E^{p,q}_0$

> The associated graded vector space $E^p_0(H^*)$ can be recovered by taking the direct sum of the spaces $E^{p,q}_0$ over the index $q$

So taking the direct sum over $q$ we get

\begin{align*}
\bigoplus_{q=0}^\infty E^{p,q}_0 &= \frac{F^pH^p}{F^{p+1}H^p}\oplus \frac{F^pH^{p+1}}{F^{p+1}H^{p+1}}\oplus\frac{F^pH^{p+2}}{F^{p+1}H^{p+2}}\oplus\dots\\
&=\frac{\oplus_{q=0}^\infty F^pH^*\cap H^{p+q}}{\oplus_{q=0}^\infty F^{p+1}H^*\cap H^{p+q}}
\end{align*}

but I have no idea how to identify
$$\frac{\oplus_{q=0}^\infty F^pH^*\cap H^{p+q}}{\oplus_{q=0}^\infty F^{p+1}H^*\cap H^{p+q}}$$
with
$$\frac{F^pH^*}{F^{p+1}H^*}$$
or if it's even possible to do it. I have a feeling that I've made an error somewhere. I'm not entirely certain if I'm justified in assuming that $q$ is non-negative for instance.

As a bonus problem, I'm also not sure about the sentence immediately after the one I quoted above

> To recover $H^r$ directly, as a vector space, take the direct sum $\bigoplus_{p+q=r}E^{p, q}_0$

so taking the example of $H^2$ we have

$$\bigoplus_{p+q=2}E_0^{p, q} = E_0^{0, 2}\oplus E_0^{1,1}\oplus E_0^{2, 0}=\frac{F^0H^2}{F^1H^2}\oplus\frac{F^1H^2}{F^2H^2}\oplus\frac{F^2H^2}{F^3H^2} \simeq \frac{H^2}{F^3H^2}$$
which clearly isn't isomorphic with $H^2$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: “I've made it through a grand total of 1 page of (insert book here)” – every math student ever with an advanced book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember $H^*$ is a graded *vector space*, so there are no extension issues. Also, there are two gradings here, which makes it a bit harder to talk about. For the sake of communicating, let's call these the $H$-grad and $F$-grade.

---

Let's say $H^*=H^0\oplus H^1\oplus H^2$. So, for example, we can call $H^2$ the $H$-grade-$2$ term of $H^*$.

Now suppose we have another filtration
$$H^*=F^0H^*\supset F^1H^*\supset F^2H^*\supset F^3H^*\supset F^4H^*=\{0\}.$$

This gives the $F$-grading

$$H^*=\frac{F^0H^*}{F^1H^*}\oplus \frac{F^1H^*}{F^2H^*}\oplus \frac{F^2H^*}{F^3H^*}\oplus \frac{F^3H^*}{F^4H^*}$$

So $F^1H^*/F^2H^*$ is the $F$-grade-$1$ term of $H^*$.

Now the point is that $F$ also induces a grading on each of the $H^i$, so

$$H^0=\frac{F^0H^0}{F^1H^0}\oplus \frac{F^1H^0}{F^2H^0}\oplus \frac{F^2H^0}{F^3H^0}\oplus \frac{F^3H^0}{F^4H^0}$$

as well as

$$H^1=\frac{F^0H^1}{F^1H^1}\oplus \frac{F^1H^1}{F^2H^1}\oplus \frac{F^2H^1}{F^3H^1}\oplus \frac{F^3H^1}{F^4H^1}$$

and

$$H^2=\frac{F^0H^2}{F^1H^2}\oplus \frac{F^1H^2}{F^2H^2}\oplus \frac{F^2H^2}{F^3H^2}\oplus \frac{F^3H^2}{F^4H^2}.$$

Since $F$ is a filtration on the vector space $H^*$, note that it is more correct to write $F^iH^*\cap H^j$ rather than $F^iH^j$. All together, $H^*$ can be split into a $4\times 3$ grid, which motivates the way we write spectral sequences in pages.

Comment: But with the way you've written $H^2$ you have that final $F^3H^2/F^4H^2$ term, which doesn't fit with the $\bigoplus_{p+q=2}E^{p, q}_0$ thing. It would require values of $q$ to be negative, which seems to not be allowed, since in the very next definition McCleary restricts values of $p$ and $q$ to be non-negative, and says in the paragraph afterwards that values of $p$ or $q < 0$ imply that $E^{p, q}_0 = \{0\}$. I understand that you are correct with the way you've written it here but I'm confused about why it's written differently in the book, has McClearly just made an error?

Comment: Also, on a slightly different topic, you say that because $H^*$ is a vector space there are no extension issues, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes I see the confusion; you're totally right but here, the statement $F^iH^j=0$ for $i>j$ is a *requirement* rather than a property of filtered complexes. This is not as harsh of a restriction as you might think, since many spectral sequences one encounters are first-quadrant anyway. There are also a bunch of nice properties of first-quadrant spectral sequences which are relatively straightforward to prove.

Comment: By extension issues, I just mean that, with integral coefficients, it is much harder to break everything up into summands and then piece it back together correctly. With field coefficients, you generally just have to keep track of the dimension of each $E^{p,q}$. For integral cohomology, you suddenly can have torsion, which means you might need to actually "look under the hood" to get the information you want (worst case scenario imo).

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes a lot more sense now. Set your answer as accepted with the clarification, thanks very much!